# Builder pattern with abstraction without requirering to override all common methods

Tags: java, builder

I am trying to create different types of builders that each would have common and unique methods, so I am trying to create some sort of abstraction for it, however I ran into an issue.
An example of my code would be:

```
// The abstract with all the common methods
public abstract class AbstractBuilder {

    public AbstractBuilder commonMethod() { 
        // implementation here
        return this;
    }

}

// Builder 1
public class MainBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {
    
    public MainBuilder mainUniqueMethod() {
        // implementation here
        return this;
    }

}

// Builder 2
public class SecondBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {
    
    public SecondBuilder secondUniqueMethod() {
        // implementation here
        return this;
    }

}
```

The issue would come when working with the builder, let's say I do

```
new MainBuilder().mainUniqueMethod().commonMethod(); // Possible
new MainBuilder().commonMethod().mainUniqueMethod(); // Impossible because commonMethod returns `AbstractBuilder`
```

So the only way around I found to fix this issue was to always override and then cast a super call to the main method like:

```
@Override
public MainBuilder commonMethod() {
    return (MainBuilder) super.commonMethod();
}
```

But this can get quite repetitive if the common methods are big enough, maybe this is a bad design, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of making this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics here:

```
public abstract class AbstractBuilder<T extends AbstractBuilder<T>> {

  public T commonMethod() { 
    // implementation here
    return getThis();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected T getThis() {
    return (T)this;
  }
}

class MainBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<MainBuilder> { ... }
```

That way the common base class gets to "know" what subtype to actually return. The `getThis()` method requires an ugly cast that might break if you'd use something like `class SecondBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<MainBuilder>` hence the warning. So take care how you're implementing the subclasses.

One way to address this would be to make `getThis()` abstract and have each subclass implement it.